# Why Recyclerview start scrolling up/down from half of the list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

Actually, I am updating "RecylerView" list adapter based on filter data list. When I update adapter data updated successfully but Scrolling start from half of adapter list.
Does anyone face problem like this before?

Things i have already tried
- Put Recyclerview inside RelativeLayout
- Set Recyclerview height to wrap_content
- Use requestLayout method

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/spinnerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp45"
        android:background="@color/black_color"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp10"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dp10"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="@string/statement_type"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:fontFamily="@string/fontBold" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/filterItemSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp45"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerLayout"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="@string/lbl_date_particular"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bodyText"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtdr_cr"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/lbl_dr_cr"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bodyText"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtbalance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|end"
            android:text="@string/balance"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/bodyText"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contentLayout"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_account_statement" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_acc_statement_available"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp18"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeLoaderLine"
        layout="@layout/custom_loaderview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Probably your view holders sizes are changing on they getting visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to adapter updates and scroll your `RecyclerView` to starting position when changes are detected.

If you're using Java:

```
//Initializing your adapter 
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(...);

//Listening to adapter updates
myAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged() {

        //Scrolling to starting position
        recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);
    }
});

//Setting your adapter on your RecyclerView
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

...
```

If you're using Kotlin:

```
//Initializing your adapter 
var myAdapter = MyAdapter(...)

//Listening to adapter updates
myAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : 
        RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onChanged() {

        //Scrolling to starting position
        myRecyclerView.layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
})

//Setting your adapter on your RecyclerView
myRecyclerView.adapter = myAdapter

...
```

Hope it helps! =)